# Having problems saving wifi config with nodemcu

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Have a development esp12 (Amica) that has been working Ok for months. On a recent boot it appeared to stop connecting to my Wifi. I have the enduser setup code in the module, that connected ok, but the config was not save thru reboot.

if I connect via a terminal and do the following

```
cfg = {}
cfg.ssid = "SSIDHERE"
cfg.pwd = "password"
cfg.save = true
cfg.auto = false
saved = wifi.sta.config(cfg)
print (saved)
false
```

Have tried erasing the flash and reloading with no change.

I am building the binaries locally

```
branch: master
        commit: 310faf7fcc9130a296f7f17021d48c6d717f5fb6
        release: 3.0-master_20190907
        release DTS: 201909070945
        SSL: false
        build type: float
        LFS: 0x20000
        modules: bit,enduser_setup,file,gpio,gpio_pulse,i2c,mqtt,net,node,ow,pcm,rotary,rtctime,sjson,sntp,spi,struct,tmr,uart,u8g2,wifi,ws2812,ws2812_effects
 build 2019-10-15 21:16 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 3.0.1-dev(fce080e)
```

Comment: Appears to be related to https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/2978

Comment: Yes it probably is the same issue. Will comment on that one

Comment: After some investigation I have found that after using wfi.setmode(1) i.e. STATION_MODE  the wifi.sta.config above returned true and does appear to have saved Ok. It was set to 3 STATIONAP_MODE. I can now save regardless of the mode and cannot  repro the problem.